# Allow empty string with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to check if there's a number in a text `input` using regular expression. Here's the code:

```
var regex = /^[0-9]+$/;
if (myInput.val().match(regex)) {
    console.log("number");
} else {
    console.log("bad");
}
```

It works well, but if I add text, then backspace all the way, I get "bad". How can I make it log "good" when there isn't anything in the text `input`? I don't want to allow spaces, but I want to allow an empty `input`.

I tried:

```
var regex = /\s ^[0-9]+$/;
```

But then whatever I insert in the `input`, I always get "bad".

Comment: Try `/^[0-9]*$/` and use `RegExp#test` instead of `String#match`

Comment: Why not just do two checks? `if (!val.length || val.match(regex))`

Comment: @Tushar Can you explain about the RegExp#test and explain why it's better than what I have?

Comment: @epascarello I thought of that, but then what's the point of doing 2 checks when I can just do 1.

Comment: You said " if there's a number in a text". Do you mean you want to match positive on `1234`, as well as on `a1a`,`1ab12` and `abd1`? Not only on text which contains only numbers, but on number/letter as well?

Comment: @yoko I don't understand what you mean by number/letters

Comment: If you are searching for a text only consisting of numbers, you will find somethime like `1234`. Only numbers in the string. But if you are searching for numbers and letters, you can get a combined string like `1a123`. Letters and numbers in one string. Which one are you looking for?

Comment: @yoko I'm looking for the combination of letters and numbers

Comment: So, a match for every of the strings : `1234`,`a1234`,`12a34`,`1234a`,`abcd` ?

Comment: @yoko That's correct.

Comment: okay, I have changed it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might fit , either you test for your Exp `(^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$)` or for an empty string `(^$)`.

```
var regex = /(^$)|(^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$)/;
if (myInput.val().match(regex)) {
    console.log("number");
} else {
    console.log("bad");
}
```

Comment: How does your answer differ from @gurvinder372's answer? Which one is recommended, and why?

Comment: In my RegEx I am trying first to check for an empty string, if this is not the case, i am checking for digits. Basically the same as gurvinder, but on the one hand i never feel comfortable with the `*` operator, on the other hand it might run faster, if you check for an empty string first, and only using the "bigger" one afterwards. Also, did you read my comment in your OP?

Comment: Is it bad to use `*` ?

Comment: imho greedy Operators are never a good thing. But since i am using `+`.. well, I did not say my solution was perfect. But since `*` catches even more than `+`, i tend to use it as less as possible.

Answer (score 1):

try this (* in place of +)

```
var regex = /^[0-9]*$/;
if (myInput.val().test(regex)) {
    console.log("number");
} else {
    console.log("bad");
}
```